# Which simplejson module to use for Google AppEngine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to figure out which simplejson module to use. Having looked back through my project I can see in some places I am using a mixture of both:

- django.utils.simplejson
- google.appengine.ext.key_range.simplejson

Which should I be using and why?

Comment: If you are on py27 you can use the native JSON library which is much faster than simplejson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you see anything recommending the use of google.appengine.ext.key_range.simplejson? That is only available because the key_range package happens to import simplejson. Don't use it like that.

Comment: I honestly don't know, I guess I just copy and pasted it from somewhere... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a least a few months now, you can simply:

```
import simplejson
```

and it works fine; no need to find it in some random package.

And, of course, in the Python 2.7 runtime, `json` is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Functionality is probably the same for both, but I would use `django.utils.simplejson`, here is why:

- `google.appengine.ext.key_range.simplejson` is not mentioned by any GAE documents so it may get removed at some point.
- `django.utils.simplejson` has more probability to being updated along with django and it seems there is less change it will be removed in the future.